Proof that $ \boxtimes $ of irreducible representations is again irreducible.
This is a follow up to a claim used in the answer to my question Can a triple product of characters be irreducible?
Apparently, if $ \rho_1: G \to GL(V) $ is an irrep and $ \rho_2: H \to GL(W) $ is an irrep then $ \rho_1 \boxtimes \rho_2 $ is irreducible. What is an easy/good proof of this fact?
Here is my proof attempt. Let $ U \subset V \otimes W $ be closed under the action of $ \rho_1 \boxtimes \rho_2 $. It is enough to show that if $ U \neq 0 $ then $ U= V \otimes W $. If $ U $ contains a non-zero simple tensor $ v \otimes w $ then the proof is immediate because simple tensors span $ V \otimes W $ and for any other simple tensor $ v' \otimes w' $ we can (by irreducibility of $ \rho_1 $ and $ \rho_2 $) find $ \sum_{g \in G} \alpha_g g$ and $ \sum_{h \in H} \beta_h h$ such that
$$
\sum_{g \in G} \alpha_g g \cdot v= v' 
$$
and
$$
\sum_{h \in H} \beta_h h \cdot w =w'
$$
But the assumption $ U \neq 0 $ only guarantees that $ U $ contains some nonzero sum of simple tensors $ \sum_{i} v_i \otimes w_i $. Not quite sure how to make the proof work in the general case with a sum of simple tensors.

The following MO question makes question this statement, though I lack the rep theory for a full assessment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/338909.

We should say which field we are working over: the statement holds for algebraically closed fields. Over a general field, we need to make the stronger assumption the irreps are actually absolutely irreducible. (This still allows for counterexamples to your other question if we just start with absolutely irreducible representations.)
First, note a useful fact from linear algebra: If $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over $k$, then the canonical map $\mathrm{End}_k(V) \otimes_k \mathrm{End}_k(W) \to \mathrm{End}_k(V \otimes W)$ is an isomorphism of $k$ algebras. Now if $V$ is a representation of $G_1$ and $W$ is a representation of $G_2$, then we get an action of $G_1$ on $\mathrm{End}_k(V)$ and an action of $G_2$ on $\mathrm{End}_k(W)$ and the above isomorphism is actually $G_1 \times G_2$-equivariant, so that we get an isomorphism for representations of $G_1 \times G_2$
$\mathrm{End}_k(V) \boxtimes \mathrm{End}_k(W) \cong \mathrm{End}_k(V \boxtimes W)$
Now we can take $G_1 \times G_2$ invariants on both sides (Using that $(V_1 \boxtimes V_2)^{G_1 \times G_2} \cong V_1^{G_1} \otimes V_2^{G_2}$, which is easily checked) and obtain
$\mathrm{End}_{k[G_1]}(V) \otimes_k \mathrm{End}_{k[G_2]}(W) \cong \mathrm{End}_{k[G_1 \times G_2]}(V \boxtimes W)$
We can use this to see that the restriction to absolutely irreducible representations is necessary. Take for example, any irreducible representation $V$ of a group $G$ over $\Bbb R$ with endomorphism ring $\Bbb C$. Then by the above, we get $\mathrm{End}_{k[G \times G]}(V \boxtimes V) \cong \Bbb C \otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$. Now $\Bbb C\otimes_{\Bbb R} \Bbb C$ is not a field (or a division algebra), it's isomorphic to $\Bbb C \times \Bbb C$, so by Schur's lemma $V \boxtimes V$ can't be irreducible.
In the semisimple case, we can also use endomorphism rings to prove that everything works for absolutely irreducible representations: if $G$ is finite and $k[G]$ is semisimple (i.e. $\operatorname{char}(k)$ doesn't divide $k[G]$), then a finite-dimensional representation $V$ is absoutely irreducible if and only $\mathrm{End}_{k[G]}(V) \cong k$. This follows from a combination of a converse to Schur's lemma (which only works in the semisimple case) and a characterization of absolutely irreducible representations among irreps by their endomorphisms. Using this, the following proof works in the semisimple case:
If $V_1$ and $V_2$ are absoutely irreducible, then $\mathrm{End}_{k[G_1]}(V_1) \cong \mathrm{End}_{k[G_2]}(V_2) \cong k$, so $\mathrm{End}_{k[G_1 \times G_2]}(V_1 \boxtimes V_2) \cong \mathrm{End}_{k[G_1]}(V_1) \otimes_k \mathrm{End}_{k[G_2]}(V_2) \cong k \otimes_k k \cong k$, thus $V_1 \boxtimes V_2$ is absoutely irreducible.

But we can do better than that: we can remove the restriction on the characteristic of $k$ and even the assumption that $G$ is finite. The key result that we want to use is the following:

If $A$ is an algebra over a field $k$ and $V$ is an $A$-module which is finite-dimensional over $k$, then $V$ is absolutely irreducible if and only if the associated map of algebras $A \to \mathrm{End}_k(V)$ is surjective.

For a proof, see this question.
Now for any groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ (not necessarily finite) and any field $k$, there's always an isomorphism of algebras $k[G_1] \otimes k[G_2] \cong k[G_1 \times G_2]$ given on the standard basis by $g_1 \otimes g_2 \mapsto (g_1,g_2)$
With all this at hand, we can prove the following result:

Let $k$ be a field and let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be groups and let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be absolutely irreducible repesentations over $k$ of $G_1$ and $G_2$, respectively, which are finite-dimensional over $k$. Then $V_1 \boxtimes V_2$ is an absolutely irreducible representation of $G_1 \times G_2$

Proof: The canonical map $k[G_1 \times G_2] \to \mathrm{End}_k(V_1 \boxtimes V_2)$ may be identified with the tensor product of the maps $k[G_1] \to \mathrm{End}_k(V_1)$ and $k[G_2] \to \mathrm{End}_k(V_2)$. As the tensor product of surjective maps is surjective, we win.

Oh, this is very nice, thank you!

You actually need hypotheses on the ground field for this to be true. Over $\mathbb{C}$ a quick-and-dirty proof is available using character theory; a character $\chi$ is irreducible iff $\langle \chi, \chi \rangle = 1$, and the external tensor product satisfies
$$\langle \chi_1 \boxtimes \phi_2, \psi_1 \boxtimes \psi_2 \rangle_{G \times H} = \langle \chi_1, \psi_1 \rangle_G \langle \chi_2, \psi_2 \rangle_H$$
so the conclusion follows.
Over $\mathbb{R}$ the statement is false. A counterexample is given by letting $G = H = C_3$ and taking both $V$ and $W$ to be the $2$-dimensional real irreducible representation given by rotations of an equilateral triangle. Then $V \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} W$ is a $4$-dimensional representation of an abelian group $C_3 \times C_3$, so it can't be irreducible; for finite abelian groups their irreducible representations over $\mathbb{R}$ are either $1$ or $2$-dimensional, since the endomorphism algebras can only be either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ (and not $\mathbb{H}$).
A more conceptual argument (still with hypotheses on the ground field) is the following. Suppose $K$ is a ground field of characteristic not dividing $|G|$ or $|H|$, so that $K[G]$ and $K[H]$ are semisimple. Consider their Artin-Wedderburn decompositions
$$K[G] \cong \prod_i M_{n_i}(D_i)$$
$$K[H] \cong \prod_j M_{n_j}(D_j)$$
where $D_i, D_j$ are division algebras over $K$. Then
$$\begin{align*} K[G \times H] &\cong K[G] \otimes_K K[H] \\
 &\cong \prod_{i, j} M_{n_i}(D_i) \otimes_K M_{n_j}(D_j) \\
 &\cong \prod_{i, j} M_{n_i n_j}(D_i \otimes_K D_j). \end{align*}$$
Each factor $M_{n_i}(D_i)$ in the Artin-Wedderburn decomposition corresponds to an irreducible representation $V_i$ with endomorphism algebra $D_i^{op}$ of dimension $n_i$ over its endomorphism algebra. So what this tensor product of the two decompositions is telling us is that, if $V_i$ is an irreducible representation of $G$ and $W_j$ is an irreducible representation of $H$, then their external tensor product satisfies
$$\text{End}(V_i \boxtimes_K W_j) \cong \text{End}(V_i) \otimes_K \text{End}(W_j) \cong D_i^{op} \otimes_K D_j^{op}$$
(there should be a direct proof of this but I don't know it; this categorifies the character identity above... also this argument may not be complete, hmm). We conclude that:

Proposition: $V_i \boxtimes_K W_j$ is irreducible iff $D_i \otimes_K D_j$ remains a division algebra.

This will generally not be true; in the $K = \mathbb{R}$ counterexample above we have $D_i \cong D_j \cong \mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ is not a division algebra.
However, it is true if $K$ is also assumed to be algebraically closed, or more generally if we assume that $D_i \cong D_j \cong K$ (irreps with this property are said to be absolutely irreducible). So:

Corollary: $V_i \boxtimes_K W_j$ is irreducible if $K$ is algebraically closed, or more generally if $V_i$ and $W_j$ are absolutely irreducible.

The fact that these nontrivial hypotheses appear tells you that a direct proof can't be too simple, e.g. you can't just get away with manipulating tensors in a way that doesn't interact with the ground field much.

Note: if you assume absolute irreducibility, then you can remove the hypothesis on the ground field (and even on the finiteness of the groups), see my answer.
